# Replace raster values with multiple other Rasters in R

Tags: raster, r

I have a main raster that only has 12 values in it 1-12.
Then I have 12 separate rasters in them with temperature data.
For every value in my main raster I want to replace the value with data from my 12 temperature rasters in R.
The rasters all have the same extent and crs.

```
valueraster <- raster("filepath\\valueraster.tif")

inputdirectory <- file.path("D:\\filepath")
outputdirectory <- file.path("D:\\otherfilepath")

jan <- raster(jan.tif)
feb <- raster(feb.tif)
mar <- raster(mar.tif)
apr <- raster(apr.tif)
may <- raster(may.tif)
jun <- raster(jun.tif)
jul <- raster(jul.tif)
aug <- raster(aug.tif)
sep <- raster(sep.tif)
oct <- raster(oct.tif)
nov <- raster(nov.tif)
dec <- raster(dec.tif)

#make an empty copy of first raster
valueraster_copy <- valueraster
```

So then, where the `valueraster` is equal to 1, I want to replace that area with the January file. When the `valueraster` is equal to 2 I want to replace that area with the February file.

I tried using the replacement function in R like so:

```
valueraster_copy[valueraster_copy == 1] <- jan
valueraster_copy[valueraster_copy == 2] <- feb
valueraster_copy[valueraster_copy == 3] <- mar
valueraster_copy[valueraster_copy == 4] <- apr
```

I did that all through to December.

Then I write out the raster

```
writeRaster(valueraster_copy, filename=file.path(output_directory, "newraster.tif"), format= "GTiff", overwrite = TRUE)
```

I get a Warning Message, `"Warning number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"`.

Then when I open up the image there's a lot of missing data. Can someone point me to a better way to do this?

Comment: It is important to move workflows to the terra package as raster is due for depreciation.  You can read the raster using `terra::rast`. Your multiple replacement task can be done with `terra::ifel` which is a raster-object specific version of  base `ifelse`. There should be considerable info online regarding use/syntax of this function.

Answer (score 1):

Jeffrey Evans is right that moving to terra is a good idea; here's a code that will work in Raster and should also work in terra with spatRaster objects:

```
valueraster_copy[valueraster == 1] <- jan[valueraster == 1]
valueraster_copy[valueraster == 2] <- feb[valueraster == 2]
valueraster_copy[valueraster == 3] <- mar[valueraster == 3]
valueraster_copy[valueraster == 4] <- apr[valueraster == 4]
```

They key point is that you don't want to replace the values of the raster that you're using for month identification; if your temperature for a cell in January is 6, you will then later replace that value with the June raster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what ended up working for me. It is not the cleanest solution and I will look more into Sacha's solution and the Terra Package. Thank you.

```
janval <- values(valueraster) == 1
values(valueraster_copy)[janval] <- values(jan)[janval]

febval <-values(valueraster) == 2
values(valueraster_copy)[febval] <- values(feb)[febval]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `terra::selectRange` for that

```
library(terra)
#your temperature filenames 
f <- paste0(tolower(month.abb), ".tif")

# create SpatRasters
temp <- rast(f)
valueraster <- rast("filename.tif")

x <- selectRange(temp, valueraster)
```